# Download image via webservice

Tags: iphone, asp.net, objective-c, web-services

Hi there
I have an IPhone application that is downloading data from a .net webservice.
The webservice uses the following:-

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class DownloadHelperService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

```
public DownloadHelperService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public byte[] Download(string fileName)
{
    return Facade.IOHelper.DownloadFileFromServer(fileName);
}
```

}

This method will in theory download an image file to the client. The issue is that this is being downloaded as Json which is inefficient.
If I take off the scriptmethod attribute and class level script then I cannot make the call from my IPhone application as it says that my method calls require the scriptmethod attributes.

If anyone can advise on the best route to download images from a webservice to an IPhone application using objective-c I would be eternally grateful

Answer (score 5):

Make the webservice return you the image url and then download the image from the url.